# Helper methods to be used in Controllers AND Views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, helpermethods

I understand I can put a helper method in a `Helper` class inside the `helper` folder in Rails. Then that method can be used in any view. And I understand I can put methods in the `ApplicationController` class and that method can be used in any controller.

Where's the proper place to put a method that is frequently used in both controllers and views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put it in the controller and call:

```
helper_method :my_method
```

from the controller.

Answer (score 9):

You can put a method in a controller and then call [`helper_method`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method) in the controller to indicate that this method is available as if it were in a helper too.

For example:

```
class ApplicationController

  helper_method :this_is_really_useful

  def this_is_really_useful
    # Do useful stuff
  end
```

This method will then be available to all controllers and to all views.

Answer (score 0):

I put helpers like the ones you describe in a module in my `lib/` directory. Given some `MyApp` application, this would go in `app/lib/my_app/helpers.rb` and look like

```
module MyApp
  module Helpers
    extend self

    def some_method
      # ...
    end 

  end
end
```

Next, you must require this module. Create a new initializer at `config/initializers/my_app.rb` that looks like

```
require 'my_app'
```

and make sure `config.autoload_paths` contains your `lib/` directory in `config/application.rb`.

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib",
                             # other paths here...
                            ]
```

Finally, include the module wherever you want to use it. **Anywhere**.

`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  include MyApp::Helpers
```

`app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include MyApp::Helpers
```

I think this is a cleaner, more testable approach to managing reusable helpers throughout your application.