# Display current time globally with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, global

I want to display the current time (of the server) with `Time.now` on all sites (different controllers).
Since the global displaying of headers/navigation bars and so on can be done within layout>application.html.erb I changed it to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Depot</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class='<%= controller.controller_name %>'>
<nav>
  <%= link_to 'Store', controller: 'store', action:'index' %>
  <%= link_to 'Products', controller: 'products', action: 'index' %>
  <span>Current time: <%= @time %></span>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I further hoped to possibly add the code to get the current time within the application_controller.rb.
Here's the code I have in there

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  @time = Time.now
end
```

Unfortunately that's not working and I have to add the @time = Time.now - code within the controller (and method) I am using. This means I'd have to fill the code in several times and isn't that against the rails - idea?

I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: Perhaps a helper is what you want that all the views can access?  If that's not something you're familiar with, I can give you more info to point you in the right direction.  Iceman's answer is good too (I was writing mine when he submitted his).

Comment: No, I am not very familiar with helpers so far. I'd highly appreciate if you could push me into the right direction.

Comment: Like I said, I think Iceman's answer is great for this problem, but you should become familiar with helpers.  I would look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775055/helper-methods-to-be-used-in-controllers-and-views-in-rails) to give you a quick idea of the syntax.  Basically, helpers are a way to make methods available to a view.  Iceman's approach using a `before_action` (or `before_filter` in pre-Rails 4.x code) run code before the controller action which in this case probably is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In application controller

```
before_action :set_time

def set_time
  @time = Time.now
end
```

Now you have `@time` available everywhere and always.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I've been looking for! :)